# Calling a method from user input in JAVA

Tags: java, user-input, shortcut

I'm looking for a way to call any given method in my class without having to do the whole `try-catch` statement.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public void Worker(String handle) throws Exception
{
    if(PROTOCOL.contains(handle)) 
    {
        System.out.println("good");
        Worker.handle;
    }
    else { 
            throw new Exception("Don't understand <" + handle + ">");
         }
}
```

`PROTOCOL` is a list of allowed commands.

I know I can say `if(input = ....){do....}` but I want to be able to do the above; call my class with the input value.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at Reflection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: Throwing generic Exception is a design problem.  Consider throwing an unchecked exception - `IllegalStateException` seems reasonable for the  posted code.  If `handle` could be changed to an enum then the only problem would be if it's null.

Comment: haha yeah I thought that it was to general. Ill change it to IllegalStateException for sure

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` will be better here as `handle` is passed as argument

Comment: What would the difference be with state and argument?
I get the obvious implication, but ist state more general vs argument is like inputting int when requiring a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your commands would look like you could use a `Map<String, Command>` which you'd then use like this:

```
Map<String, Command> PROTOCOL = ... //you build that map somehow

Command c = PROTOCOL.get(handle);
if( c != null ) {
    System.out.println("good");
    c.execute();
} else { 
    throw new Exception("Don't understand <" + handle + ">");
}
```

`Command` could then be a class or function interface:

```
interface Command {
  void execute();
}
```

**Used as a class interface**

```
class MyCommand implements Command {
  //this can have private data

  void execute() {
    //do whatever is needed
  }
}

PROTOCOL.put("mycommand", new MyCommand(/*you could pass parameters here*/));
```

Advantages:

- The interface can have more than 1 method, e.g. it could have a `String getName()` as well.
- Commands can have parameters, e.g. you could provide one implementation and use different names that are bound to the same command with different parameters (e.g. a "increment" and "decrement" could be bound to `AddCommand(1)` and `AddCommand(-1)`).
- You could use some dependency inversion mechanism (e.g. via CDI) to have commands register themselves to `PROTOCOL`. That way you could even add commands via some plugin mechanism.
- Using interfaces for classes might be easier to grasp for others.
- Easier to structure for larger commands as you can easily extract the classes into separate files.

**Used as a function interface (e.g. via lambdas)**

```
PROTOCOL.put("mycommand", () -> { 
  //do whatever is needed
});
```

Advantages:

- No classes needed which can be more concise for short commands.

Comment: So you're saying that I should make my protocol list a hashmap with two prarams, (name, method) then I can call it that way or  make an interface.

Comment: @1nn15 As far as I understand your question (which is quite short) your protocol would basically consist of a list of "keywords" that are _mapped_ to some code. Thus using a map (which could be a hashmap) seems to be a good fit. You'd need the interface as well (i.e. not "or" but "and") as the map's value type.

Comment: ahh ok, I get that.

Comment: I guess trying to be lazy only makes things more complicated XD

Comment: `Command` interface is unnecessary here, you can use `Runnable` or `Callable`

Comment: @rkosegi Please clarify if you can

Comment: @1nn15 : here `Command` interface declares essentially same contract as already exists in JRE : `java.lang.Runnable` or `java.util.concurrent.Callable`.

Comment: @rkosegi that depends, the problem is that I just used the minimum for what a command might look like but the OP might actually need more. Besides that, using a specialized interface might help reduce errors and document intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use try-catch (handle exceptions yourself) then declare those exceptions on the calling method followed after throws keyword.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html

Basically you are delegating the exception handling to the caller of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example showing some things that you can do using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Note: I decided to store available methods in a list, but this could be easily modified to use a predefined list of Strings. I also threw an unchecked IllegalArgumentException from the worker method.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Worker {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1 called");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2 called");
    }

    public void worker(String handle) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Class<? extends Worker> clazz = this.getClass();
        List<Method> methods = Arrays.asList(clazz.getMethods());

        if (methods.stream().map(m -> m.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(handle)) {
            try {
                Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(handle);
                method.invoke(this);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Don't understand <" + handle + ">");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Worker().worker("method1");
        new Worker().worker("method2");
        new Worker().worker("method3");
    }
}
```